# R Graph not displaying correct data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good afternoon,

I am creating a graph in R which displays the amount of claims by claim status (i.e. settled, open, void etc). The graph is not displaying the data which is in the data table, instead it is pulling numbers which do not appear in the datatable.

The code is below:

```
tempL <- setDT(All_Data)

temp1 <- tempL

temp1 <- subset(temp1,temp1$Data == "Claims")

temp1$YM1_DATE <- lubridate::ymd(paste0(year_month = temp1$Incident.Year.Month, day = "01"))

temp1$YM1_DATE <- as.Date(temp1$YM1_DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

temp1$YM1_DATE <- ifelse(temp1$YM1_DATE > Latest_Date2, 0, temp1$YM1_DATE)

temp1 <- temp1[temp1$YM1_DATE != 0,]

temp1$YM1_DATE <- as.Date(temp1$YM1_DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1970-01-01")

MAX_MON <- max(temp1$YM1_DATE)

temp1 <- temp1[YM1_DATE >= (MAX_MON %m-% months (rollmonths)), lapply(.SD,sum), by = list(YM1_DATE,ClaimStatus),
               .SDcols = c("ClaimCount")]

ClaimStatusGraph <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = temp1, aes (x = YM1_DATE, y = ClaimCount, group = ClaimStatus, color = ClaimStatus), size = 0.75) + 
  scale_color_brewer("Blues") + 
  ggtitle("Claim Status") + 
  scale_y_continuous() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = "months", date_labels = "%Y-%m") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = 'black'), axis.line.x = element_line(color = 'black'),
        legend.position = "right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

ClaimStatus_Graph
```

This creates a graph which does not correlate to the dataset, for example declined is 20 on the graph instead of 61.

I can add images if this helps. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The dput(temp1) gives the following:

structure(list(YM1_DATE = structure(c(17775, 17775, 17805, 17836, 
17956, 17956, 17956, 17836, 17956, 17836, 17805, 17836, 17987, 
17987, 17987, 17987, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17987, 18017, 18017, 
18017, 18017, 18017, 17805, 17866, 17866, 18048, 18048, 18048, 
18048, 18048, 18078, 18078, 18078, 18078, 18078, 17897, 17897, 
17897, 17897, 18109, 18109, 18109, 18109, 18109, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18201, 
18201, 18201, 18201, 18201, 17928, 17928, 17928, 17928, 17928, 
17956), class = "Date"), ClaimStatus = c("Declined", "Void", 
"Declined", "Declined", "Settled", "InActive", "Void", "Settled", 
"Declined", "InActive", "Settled", "Void", "Declined", "Settled", 
"Open", "Void", "InActive", "Declined", "Settled", "InActive", 
"Declined", "Open", "Settled", "InActive", "Void", "InActive", 
"Void", "Recovery", "Declined", "Settled", "Open", "Void", "InActive", 
"Settled", "Declined", "Open", "Void", "InActive", "Settled", 
"Declined", "InActive", "Void", "Open", "Settled", "Declined", 
"InActive", "Void", "Settled", "Open", "Declined", "Void", "InActive", 
"Open", "Settled", "Declined", "Void", "InActive", "Open", "Settled", 
"Declined", "InActive", "Void", "Declined", "Settled", "InActive", 
"Open", "Void", "Open"), ClaimCount = c(2, 1, 9, 23, 213, 61, 
6, 49, 91, 19, 21, 2, 93, 198, 100, 5, 46, 48, 68, 1, 129, 83, 
241, 5, 6, 6, 5, 1, 100, 316, 112, 15, 3, 336, 134, 129, 8, 8, 
91, 63, 33, 5, 175, 238, 113, 6, 13, 219, 113, 100, 9, 8, 145, 
218, 68, 11, 3, 392, 110, 61, 9, 11, 92, 152, 53, 1, 5, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-68L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = )

[image: Graph Capture]

[image: Data Set Capture]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We can't confirm that it does not correlate as you haven't added data to the question. Try `dput(temp1)`

Comment: I have just added this into the post. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be working for me - 'Declined' is showing at 61 for at 2019-11 on the graph if that's what you're pointing to? perhaps adding a picture of your graph might be a helpful next steps. It might also be that the blues palette is making 'Declined' too light to see on another screen.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Try simple `ggplot(temp1) + geom_line(aes(YM1_DATE, ClaimCount, color = ClaimStatus))` and look if you still have a problem

Comment: I have added images.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, try code that I added. Declined is at 61

Comment: I've put some more data through the code and now seems to be working so it's an error with the dataset rather than the graph. Thanks for your help.